# How to punish a riffle shuffle?

Tags: probability, random, card-games

It is common knowledge that for a deck to be considered randomly sorted, at least seven riffle shuffles should be used. However, in my experience, very few people will take the time to complete seven full riffle shuffles. Although I know there must be a systematic non-randomness in the deck, how could I use this to my advantage? If I saw a 2, 5, 6 go in the discard pile in the previous game, and I drew the same 2, should I expect a larger probability to draw a 5 than any other number? And if I draw a 5, what does that say about the 6?

Comment: All the gory details in "Aldous, D. and Diaconis, P. "Shuffling Cards and Stopping Times." Amer. Math. Monthly 93, 333-348, 1986."

Comment: Well, if you'd memorized the deck and there was just a single riffle shuffle, you could possibly (though it might take a few draws to figure out where the deck was cut if some cards are indistinguishable) know that your draw could only be one of two cards. This breaks when some cards are kept secret, though, which seems to typically be the case in card games. (i.e. your opponent doesn't show their hand)

Comment: In bridge, at least, you tend to expect "flatter" deals when there is insufficient shuffling. I've never seen this proven mathematically, since it is heavily dependent on how the previous deal was "gathered," for which I've never seen any kind of mathematical model.